# MySQL select "related" rows

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to select related rows in a MySQL table with "MATCH AGAINST"

**Table: Article**

```
ID | headline | content
```

How can I select related rows that match the headline and content of ID1, ID3 and ID7.
The following is not correct, but I hope this will clarify the problem:

```
SELECT ID from article 
where 
    MATCH(headline, content) AGAINST(headline, content) AND
    find_in_set(ID, "1,3,7")
```

**EDIT**

The headline and content of the rows with the ID 1, 3, 7 are as follows

Headline: "some headline", "another headline", "lorem ipsum"

Content: "some content", "another content", "Lorem ipsum"

Now, I try to find articles where the headline+content match against(**"some headline", "another headline", "lorem ipsum", "some content", "another content", "Lorem ipsum"**)

**EDIT 2**

I know that a user has read the articles with the ID 1, 3 and 7. Now I would like to display him related articles.

Comment: Please edit your question, providing sample data and desired results.

Comment: Didn't understand the results you're hoping to get!!!

Comment: The added explanation still isn't quite clear enough. Please edit to include full sample table rows formatted as a table (highlight and use the `{}` button or `ctl-k`) and also a table showing what your query output should be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have FULLTEXT index on both the columns together.  `FULLTEXT (headline, content)`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html